# Array of UIViews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uikit

is there a way to create an array of UIViews?

I've tried bot I can't add an values

```
var views = [UIView?](count: 64, repeatedValue: nil)
```

This results in nil

```
views[0]?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

I also tried

```
var views = NSMutableArray()
for (var a = 0; a<100; a++){
        views[a] = UIView()
}
views[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() // fails
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this line:

```
var views = [UIView?](count: 64, repeatedValue: nil)
```

you are creating an array of optionals, filled in with `nil` - that is what you set with the `repeatedValue` parameter. The correct way would be:

```
var views = [UIView](count: 64, repeatedValue: UIView())
```

Note however that it creates one `UIView` instance only, and assigns it to all 64 elements.
Also, unless there's a specific reason, I don't think you need an array of optionals, so should consider using `[UIView]`

That said, if you want an array of unique instances, you can use this code:

```
var views = [UIView]()
for _ in 1...100 {
    views.append(UIView())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var views = [UIView]()
views.reserveCapacity(100) // not necessary but improves performance just a little bit
for var i = 0; i < 100; i++ {
        views.append(UIView())
}
views[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 4, you can use one of the following ways in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `Range` and `map(_:)`

```
let range = 0 ... 5
let array = range.map { _ in UIView() }
```

---

### #2. Using `Range` and for loop

```
var array = [UIView]()
for _ in 0 ..< 5 {
    array.append(UIView())
    //array += [UIView()] //also works
}
```

---

### #3. Using `AnyIterator`

```
let anyIterator = AnyIterator(UIView.init)
let array = Array(anyIterator.prefix(5))
```

---

### #4. Using a custom struct that conforms to `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol` protocols

```
struct ViewSequence: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    let count: Int
    private var index = 0

    init(count: Int) {
        self.count = count
    }

    mutating func next() -> UIView? {
        guard index < count else { return nil }
        defer { index = index.advanced(by: 1) }
        return UIView()
    }

}

let sequence = ViewSequence(count: 5)
let array = Array(sequence)
```